# call to js function from aspx source

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I wrote a Javascript function in the code-behind like this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
    Page.ClientScript.GetType(),
    "MyScript",
    "<script type='text/javascript'>" +
        "var urls="+s +
        "function carousel(params) { ... }" +
    "</script>");
```

How can I call to the javascript function **that I wrote in the code-behind** on the client' side (on the level of the ASPX page)?

Comment: If registered correctly, then, yes - you can call this function in your frontside HTML.

Comment: it isn't work- i don't know what the problen..the way that i register the function is true??

Comment: _HOW_ doesn't it work? Be more descriptive! Have you looked at the resulting HTML? Does it look proper? Do you try to call the function before it's declared in the HTML source?

Comment: this code suppose to make an carousel of images.. when i wrote the code in the aspx page- it make this carousel in the page and now- not!!

Comment: is there a way to debug the js code in visual studio?

Comment: Actually there is but using Chrome or Firebug much more easier. just hit F12.

Comment: i saw now that the js code insert into the <body> and not into the <head>, can i have a way to determine from the code-behind where the js code will be place?

Comment: Even though code got inserted into the body, that doesn't make any difference. Your global code should still be accessible and callable.

Answer (score 0):

In the markup of the page, you simply need to make a reference to the function - typically in an event handler, such as onClick, just as you would with any other javascript function, and understanding you'd have to provide for your parameters as appropriate...eg

```
<input type='button' onclick="carousel(1)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ***Important note**: While this is a legitimate way of adding a javascript function it is strongly advisable not to do it this way, because you're mixing server and client side code. Doing this frequently will lead to a hardly maintainable codebase.*

### Your function is global client-side function

Your function is defined in the global scope, so it's directly accessible to client side scripts as:

```
carousel(params);
```

But you have to make sure that no other global function overrides it (in case you've been trying to call it but got unexpected results).

### Function still not defined?

There may be lots of reasons why function's not defined. May also be that your function has some syntax error.

Anyway. You can always check global function using development tools in browsers (Firebug in Firefox or Development tools in Chrome). Just press <kbd>F12</kbd> and it'll show up. Open Script tag and inspect...

If you can't find your function, you can check its syntax by copying it from your code behind (while of course sanitising those string quotes) into the console window of browser dev tools and see what browser thinks of it. :)

Comment: @sagit: I've proposed one reason. Some other global function overrides yours.

Comment: it's seems that the source code don't know the carousel func..
i call the func like this: <script type='text/javascript'>  
                          
                carousel(params);
      </script>

Comment: @sagit: Well use developer tools to investigate your problem as suggested otherwise you won't get too far with this problem of yours.

Comment: i saw now that the js code insert into the <body> and not into the <head>, can i have a way to determine from the code-behind where the js code will be place?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the urls variable looks like wrong. I don t know it is your real code or not but try this for the line and line breaks at the end of every line.

```
"var urls='"+s + "';\n"
```

Secondly you should use `Page.GetType()`

and for calling after that you can call it as a JS function in your html page as usual but if you want to call it registering by ASP.Net page you should use `RegisterStartupScript` as it is registered end of the page.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    Page.GetType(),
    "callScript",
    "<script type='text/javascript'>" +
        "carousel('"+paramFromServerSide+"');" +
    "</script>");
```

[More From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Try following code

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = "Hello"; // change it what ever you have i used it for testing
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
        Page.GetType(),
       "MyScript",
       "<script type='text/javascript'>" +
        "var urls=" +"'"+s+"';\nfunction carousel() { alert(urls); }" +
        "</script>");     
    }
```

I have used Button control.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="carousel();"  Text="Click Me" />
```

If you want to use parameter in JavaScript function


[image]
Use following code

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string s = "www.stackoverflow.com";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
    Page.GetType(),
   "MyScript",
   "<script type='text/javascript'>" +
    "var urls=" +"'"+s+"';\nfunction carousel(param) { alert('param value:'+param+'  s value:'+urls); }" +
    "</script>");         
    }


<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="carousel(1);" Text="Click Me" />
```

hope fully it will help you to go to right direction.